# Replacing values in a string expression based on a matrix and iterating over columns

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, matrix

In column `X` are those variables that will have values in each column j, in this case only `U1`, `X4` and `U2` have values, the rest of the variables belonging to the list `['B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2']` will all have their values `0`

```py
#example matrix
new_matrix = [[ 'C',  'X', 'B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2'], 
              [ 0.0, 'U1',   8,  2.0,  1.0, -1.0,    0,    0,  1.0,    0], 
              ['+M', 'X4',   2,  1.0,  1.0,    0,  1.0,    0,    0,    0], 
              ['+M', 'U2',   8,  1.0,  2.0,    0,    0, -1.0,    0,  1.0]]

variables = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2', 'B'] #select the first row (only variables)
variables_j_col_values = [[variables.pop(variables.index('B'))] + variables, []] # --> ['B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2']
```

**The problem with this is that I need create the following matrix of values of the variables (without using libraries)** where I would have the following:

```py
variables_j_col_values = [['B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2'], 
                          [ 0 ,    0,    0,    0,    2,    0,    8,    8],    #column new_matrix[][2]
                          [ 0 ,    0,    0,    0,  1.0,    0,  2.0,  1.0],    #column new_matrix[][3]
                          [ 0 ,    0,    0,    0,  1.0,    0,  1.0,  2.0],    #column new_matrix[][4]
                          [ 0 ,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, -1.0,    0],    #column new_matrix[][5]
                          [ 0 ,    0,    0,    0,  1.0,    0,    0,    0],    #column new_matrix[][6]
                          [ 0 ,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, -1.0],    #column new_matrix[][7]
                          [ 0 ,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  1.0,    0],    #column new_matrix[][8]
                          [ 0 ,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,  1.0], ]  #column new_matrix[][9]
```

After create the `variables_j_col_values`, go replacing the values of the rows (except for row 0 of the `variables_j_col_values` array because it is a header) in the string inside `funcion_obj_z`
The logic would be to use a loop that goes through the rows, and does a
`.replace(new_matrix[][n], this_element)`

```py
funcion_obj_z = 'Z = 3 * X1 + 2 * X2 + 0 * X3 + 0 * X4 + 0 * X5 + M * U1 + M * U2'
```

In this way, using said string as an expression, it would obtain these prints in the console if it printed the value of `j_func` in each `j` iteration. These would be the desired **correct output**:

```py
#for loop, print the j string replacement the values in the string

j_func = 'Z = 3 * 0 + 2 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 2 + 0 * 0 + M * 8 + M * 8' #iteration 1
j_func = 'Z = 3 * 0 + 2 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 1.0 + 0 * 0 + M * 2.0 + M * 1.0' #iteration 2
j_func = 'Z = 3 * 0 + 2 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 1.0 + 0 * 0 + M * 1.0 + M * 2.0' #iteration 3
j_func = 'Z = 3 * 0 + 2 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * -1.0 + M * 0' #iteration 4
j_func = 'Z = 3 * 0 + 2 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 1.0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 0' #iteration 5
j_func = 'Z = 3 * 0 + 2 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * -1.0' #iteration 6
j_func = 'Z = 3 * 0 + 2 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 1.0 + M * 0' #iteration 7
j_func = 'Z = 3 * 0 + 2 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + M * 0 + M * 1.0' #iteration 8
```

Comment: So something like `for row in variables_j_col_values[1:]: print('Z = 3 * {} + 2 * {} + 0 * {} + 0 * {} + 0 * {} + M * {} + M * {}'.format(*row[1:]))`?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal a loop like that might work once you get the `variables_j_col_values` array, the problem is how to get it. Then with a for loop like the one mentioned, I could go through it and replace the values. I think the most difficult thing is to create the array `variables_j_col_values`, I tried in several ways but I can't get a good result

Comment: You talked about different desired outputs, so it's hard to tell what exactly your question is. I think I see what you want the transformation to do, so I'll try to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Albeit an ugly solution, this should give you the transformation you need:

```py
new_matrix = [[ 'C',  'X', 'B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2'], 
              [ 0.0, 'U1',   8,  2.0,  1.0, -1.0,    0,    0,  1.0,    0], 
              ['+M', 'X4',   2,  1.0,  1.0,    0,  1.0,    0,    0,    0], 
              ['+M', 'U2',   8,  1.0,  2.0,    0,    0, -1.0,    0,  1.0]]

variables = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'U2', 'B']

# create empty matrix
variables_j_col_values = [[0 for _ in range(len(variables))] for _ in range(len(new_matrix[0])-1)]

# replace first row with sorted variables based on new_matrix headers
variables_j_col_values[0] = sorted(variables, key=lambda x: new_matrix[0].index(x))

# loop over all value rows
for row in new_matrix[1:]
    # get correct column in variables_j_col_values based
    col = variables_j_col_values[0].index(row[1])
    # zip the values and rows and update accordingly
    for val, target in zip(row[2:], variables_j_col_values[1:]):
        target[col] = val
```